# parse saveInBackgroundWithBlock

Tags: multithreading, parse-platform, save

I am new to objective c.
I'm trying to set save button unable when I press save button. And doing saveInBackgroundWithBlock as well.

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: '-[UIKeyboardTaskQueue waitUntilAllTasksAreFinished] may only be called from the main thread.'

here is my code
`

```
    saveButton.enabled = NO;

PFQuery *medQuery = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:medicineClassName];

    // Retrieve the object by id
    [medQuery getObjectInBackgroundWithId:self.receiveObjectId block:^(PFObject *medObject, NSError *error) {

    // Now let's update it with some data
    NSNumberFormatter *formatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
    [medObject setObject:[formatter numberFromString:self.medIDTF.text] forKeyedSubscript:@"medID"];

        // Medicine image
        NSData *imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.medImage.image, 0.8f);
        NSMutableString *tmpString = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
        tmpString = [self filenameEncoderFromString:(NSMutableString *)self.medMerEngNameTF.text];

        NSString *fileName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", tmpString];

        PFFile *imageFile = [PFFile fileWithName:fileName data:imageData];
        /*
        if (imageFile == nil) {

            [medObject setObject:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Ironman head.png"] forKey:@"medImage"];
        } else {

            [medObject setObject:imageFile forKeyedSubscript:@"medImage"];
        }*/
        [medObject setObject:imageFile forKey:@"medImage"];

        // other Medicine columns
        tmpString = [self filenameEncoderFromString:(NSMutableString *)self.medMerEngNameTF.text
                     ];
        [medObject setObject:tmpString forKeyedSubscript:@"medMerEngName"];
        [medObject setObject:self.medMerChiNameTF.text forKeyedSubscript:@"medMerChiName"];
        [medObject setObject:self.medScienceTF.text forKeyedSubscript:@"medScienceName"];
        [medObject setObject:self.medCategoryTF.text forKeyedSubscript:@"medCategory"];

        // show progress when saving
        MBProgressHUD *hud = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
        hud.mode = MBProgressHUDAnimationFade;
        hud.labelText = @"Uploading...";
        [hud showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
            float progress = 0.0f;
            while (progress < 1.0f) {

                progress += 0.01f;
                hud.progress = progress;
                usleep(10000);
            }
        }];

        // update medicine to parse
        [medObject saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL successed, NSError *error) {        
            if (successed == YES) {
                  // show success message and hide the saving progress
                  MBProgressHUD *hudd = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
                  hudd.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
                  hudd.labelText = @"Upload Successfully";
                  hudd.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark@2x.png"]];
                    [hudd showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{
                        //
                        [self setUneditable];
                        [hud hide:YES];
                    } completionBlock:^{
                        //                MedicineTableViewController *mtvd = [[MedicineTableViewController alloc] init];
                        //                [mtvd download];
                        // Notify table view to reload the medicines from parse cloud
                        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshParse" object:self];

                    }];
```

`

thanks you help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why you are getting this error is because you are trying to affect the UI from a background thread. saveInBackgroundWithBlock executes the block on a background thread -- thus making UI code unsafe and unstable. In your block you should wrap your HUD updates using GCD (Grand Central Dispatch). You will also need to make your NSNotification call the same way:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            MBProgressHUD *hudd = [MBProgressHUD showHUDAddedTo:self.view animated:YES];
            hudd.mode = MBProgressHUDModeCustomView;
            hudd.labelText = @"Upload Successfully";
            hudd.customView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"37x-Checkmark@2x.png"]];
            [hudd showAnimated:YES whileExecutingBlock:^{

            [self setUneditable];
            [hud hide:YES];

        });

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"refreshParse" object:self];

        });
```

That should work for you.

Comment: thank you so much.@mrbcg. it works!!! But a little stupid thing is if MBProgress still running and swtich to the next task saveInBackground, MBProgress stop immediately. that's not what i want either for the user as well. THANKS!

Comment: sorry, I am too new for this site, before I just seach the answer for me, is that i click the tick into green?